# When does Android make first call to View.onMeasure() after setContentView() in Activity.onCreate()?

Tags: android, view, lifecycle

Suppose an Android Activity calls setCurrentView() for an XML-defined layout containing one or more Views to bind it in the usual manner:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ... other stuff
    MyCustomViewClass mcv = (MyCustomViewClass)findViewById(R.id.mcv);
    mcv.setSomeValues(x,y,z);
    // ... more stuff
    // ... ok, finished with everything in onCreate()
}
```

Is the call to that Activity's onCreate() method GUARANTEED to finish executing and return before Android makes its first call to the onMeasure() method for any child View declared in R.layout.activity_main? Or is Android entitled to start making calls to onMeasure() at any time during or after the call is made to setContentView()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of onCreate the Activity isn't even on screen yet (it won't be until onStart is called).  So it won't try to lay anything out until then, since it isn't on screen and thus doesn't need to be laid out.